# How do I uninstall a programm

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

I have it mounted by I can't find where I uninstall programmes.

In windows you just go to Control Panel in osx I am lost!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uninstalling applications in Mac OS X  is very different than uninstalling in a Microsoft Windows environment because Mac OS X has nothing like the Windows Registry. While most Windows programs include an uninstaller that can be run through using the Add/Remove Programs control panel, no such feature exists in Mac OS X and so most users **simply move application bundles  (see below) to the Trash**. However, often times there is more to uninstalling than a simple drag-and-drop to the trash. This article will guide you on how to fully uninstall applications.

[wiki](http://guides.macrumors.com/Uninstalling_Applications_in_Mac_OS_X)

Answer (score 1):

Just drag the application to the trash.

Some applications leave other files behind, typically in `~/Library/Application Support` or `~/Library/Preferences`, that you may want to remove, too. (They're easy to find and typically have the name of the program in their filenames.)

Answer (score 0):

Some applications which use installers have an "uninstall" feature in the installer package which you used to install them.

In this case, simply run the installation application again and look for a button or drop down menu which gives you an **uninstall** option.

Answer (score 0):

There are "uninstall" utilities that combine the trashing the application plus cleaning up the ~/Library subfolders. E.g. AppZapper - http://www.appzapper.com/